# Find area of the fourth triangle given the area of three triangles.

Tags: area

This is the question that I got in `TCS Ninja` under the `Quantitative` section.

[image: Help]

How shall I do this? Help !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote by $[...]$ the area of the polygon $...$

> **Lema 1**
>
> Let $ABCD$ be a rectangle a $P$ a point inside as shown. It follows that $$[APB]+[DPC]=[APD]+[CPB]$$ [image]

**Proof**

Draw the parallels to $AD$ and $AB$ through $P$. Then
$$[APB]+[DPC]=\frac{AB·FP}{2}+\frac{DC·EP}{2}=\frac{AB·FP+AB·DC}{2}=\frac{AB·EF}{2}=\frac{[ABCD]}{2}$$

Now back to your problem $$A1+A3=2081=A2+A4=1016+A4\iff A4=2081-1016=\color{red}{1065}$$

Thanks for the correction @Jean Marie.

Comment: The final calculations should be revised : $A_1+A_3=2081$ etc...

Comment: You're totally right. Thanks @JeanMarie

Comment: I had a look at this issue trying to find an answer to a contradiction I find in the following question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3174470 to which I have given an answer some hours ago. Maybe, you  have an idea (see my Edit)