# find a certain ratio of areas in a triangle where other areas are given

Tags: geometry, triangles, area

Given : [BDE]=8, [BDC]=12, [CDF]=9

where [.] is the area of the respective triangles.

Find ratio [AFD]/[AED] from the figure.

[image]

NOTE:-Question may have errors please just edit that or comment the error.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your problem sir. It is question of a book but i can see it is correct

Comment: 'And' is use for the sentence not for the problem

Comment: No other hypotheses on triangle ABC ?

Comment: Yes there is nothing else given

Comment: IS YOUR CAPS KEY STUCK? All caps is considered rude, the typographical equivalent of shouting. Please edit it out of your question.

Comment: Some word are capital so that it can be easily observed so that people can  pay attention on them

Comment: As the link to your figure was broken, I have included one I have done. Please, say if my solution with its two "Edits" is understandable for you. It is by exchanging that such a site remains a living body.

Comment: Don't worry, unknown, I fixed it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us give the names $x:=[ADF]$ and $y:=[ADE]$.

[image]

*Fig. 1.*

We are going to prove that

> $$x=21 \ \text{and} \ y= 20 \ \ \implies \ \ [ADF]/[ADE]=x/y=21/20.$$

In fact, we have :

$$\dfrac{x+y+9}{20}=\dfrac{9+x}{12} \ (a) \ \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \ \dfrac{x+y+8}{21}=\dfrac{8+y}{12} \ (b)\tag{1}$$

Let us explain the first equality (a)

(1)(a) is equivalent to

$$\dfrac{[ACE]}{[BCE]}=\dfrac{[ACD]}{[BCD]} \tag{2}$$

(2) can be transformed in the following equivalent expression :

$$\dfrac{\tfrac12 CE \times h_1}{\tfrac12 CE \times h_2}=\dfrac{\tfrac12 CD \times h_1}{\tfrac12 CD \times h_2}\tag{3}$$

Explnation for the equivlence between (2) and (3) : We have considered triangles $AEC$ and $BEC$ in particular as having a common base $EC$ ; we have defined $h_1$ (resp. $h_2$) as the height, i.e., the length of the altitude dropped from $A$ (resp $B$) on this common base $EC$ (we have used the classical formula for the area of a triangle : $\tfrac12$ base $\times$ height).

(3) is evidently true ! Thus  (1)(a) is established.

The second identity (1)(b) can be explained in exactly the same way.

Now, convert (1) (a) and (b) into a linear system,

$$\begin{cases}-2x&+&3y&=&18 \ \ \ (a)\\ \ \ \ 4x&-&3y&=&24 \ 
 \ \ (b)\end{cases}$$

and solve it to obtain $x$ and $y$.

---

**Edit : 2 important issues**

1) An existence issue **could** have occured. Indeed, we have been here in the logic of a "necessary condition" :  **if such a configuration of points exists with these area values $8, 12, 9$ then $x=...$, $y=...$**. But, the set of conditions could have been self-contradictory (for example with areas $10,1,10$ instead of $8,12,9$). Happily, this is not the case. There are solutions ; there are even *many* of them (see Fig. 2) ; this aspect is developed in the next section.

2) As always, it is interesting to ask, in particular for these geometrical issues, what are the **invariant transformations**.

a) It is clear that horizontal transvections (horizontal shears) :

$$\text{for any} \ u, \ \ S_u=\begin{pmatrix}1&u\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

do not modify areas because their determinant is one.

b) But there is another family of transformations, with matrices with determinant 1 as well :

$$\text{for any} \ v \neq 0, \ \ R_v=\begin{pmatrix}v&0\\0&1/v\end{pmatrix}$$

that have the same effect : indeed, starting from a solution like the blue triangle on Fig. 2, one can enlarge its base $BC$ by a factor $v$ while compressing the vertical direction (i.e. the ordinates of all points) using a factor $1/v$.

Combining operations $S_u$ and $R_v$, we generate all triangles that are solutions to the problem. One could add a general rotation $T_{\theta}$ to account for a supplementary degree of freedom in the group $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ of matrices with determinant 1, which is a necessary and sufficient condition for area preservation. Doing that, combination $T_{\theta}R_vS_u$ is called the Iwasawa decomposition. See http://www.math.polytechnique.fr/xups/xups07-02.pdf.

[image]

*Fig. 2 : Different solutions obtained from an initial one (blue triangle) by submitting it either to horizontal shears (red triangles, using $S_u$)  or to extensions-compressions (magenta triangles, using $R_v$).*

A key observation for obtaining explicit general coordinates of points $A,B,C,D,E,F$ (this constitute a second method I will not expand here) is to observe that, once the base $BC$ is fixed, $D$ has to be chosen on a certain horizontal line, the same for $E$ and $F$. One finds in this way the following general form (attesting the dependency on two parameters $d$ and $w$ that can take any $>0$ value) :

$$\begin{cases}
A&=&(a;70/w)  \ \text{with} \ a=35d/6+w/6\\
B&=&(-w;0)\\
C&=&(w;0)\\
D&=&(d;12/w)\\
E&=&(e;20/w) \ \text{with} \ e=5d/3 - 2w/3\\
F&=&(f;21/w)  \ \text{with} \ f=7d/4 + 3w/4
\end{cases}$$

Please note that parameters $d$ and $w$ have a clear  geometrical interpretation : $2w$ is the width $BC$ of triangle $ABC$, and $d$ is the abscissa of $D$. Coordinates of $D$ account for the fact that the area of triangle $BCD$ is $12$ ; the ordinates of $E$ and $F$ can be understood in the same way. Abscissas of $A,E$ and $F$ look more complicated : they have been obtained by alignment constraints ($C,D,E$ must be aligned ; the same for $BDF$).

Comment: Nice approach! Whether this triangle exists or not, is definitively very intriguing...

Comment: @Dr. Mathva : I have finally found solutions ; even more a way to have many many of them...